# how to determine sum of series step by step?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left({5\over n(n+1)} + \frac1{3^n}\right)=\frac {11}2$

so the first one is telescoping series, converge to $1$?, what kind of series is the next one?
i know i can split it to $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{5\over n(n+1)}$ +$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3^n} = 5\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n(n+1)} + \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3^n}$ , then what am i supposed to do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series is actually sum of two series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n(n+1)}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{3^n}$$

---

Now,
$$\frac1{r(r+1)}=\frac{r+1-r}{r(r+1)}=\cdots$$

See  [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

---

For $|b|<1,$
$$a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b^n=\frac a{1-b}$$

See infinite Geometric Series sum [derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series)

Comment: how to find r when it isn't geometric series?

Comment: @problematic, Please find the edited answer

Comment: @lab Should "$r+1-1$" be "$r+1-r$"?

Comment: @MickA, Sorry for the typo